# Rails rask with crontabs wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

this is my task:

```
namespace :domimoto do
  desc "test"
  task :addpepito => :environment do
    Motorizado.create!(:name => "test")
    puts "test"
  end
end
```

and this is my crontabs line:

```
* * * * * cd /home/rails4/current && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake domimoto:addpepito RAILS_ENV=production
```

and it wont create the record on the DB...

edit:

i also tried:

```
* * * * * cd /home/rails4/current && bundle exec /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake domimoto:addpepito RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Using bundler?  If so, try `* * * * * cd /home/rails4/current && bundle exec /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ra/rake domimoto:addpepito RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: yes im using bundler, but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

well I found a fix for my problem, but realy cant understand it, if it helps anyone, here it is:

I added a path reference to my crontabs, now it looks like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/bin

* * * * * cd /home/rails4/current && bundle exec rake domimoto:addpepito RAILS_ENV=production >> /home/cron.log
```

if anyone knows why this works and the others not, please tell me.